# Travis CI: FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to get my application working w/ Travis CI but I keep getting: `FATAL:  database "skateparks_test" does not exist`. I've followed the [instructions](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/database-setup/) on their website for PostgreSQL but can't seem to get it to work. If you would like to take a look at my .travis.yaml file you can do so at:

https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web/blob/master/.travis.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the file extension should be .yml, not .yaml, as in `.travis.yml`

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: PS: with script: "bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate spec"
it is not necessary to include before_script:
  - "psql -c 'create database skateparks_test;' -U postgres"

Answer (score 0):

yea looks like the yml file is doing the database creation, and if the file was named wrong, you won't get the database creation.

I have no idea what travis-ci is but it shouldn't be any harder for you to just create a database manually without the yml file. Just go into a postgres shell.